# Indy 10.6 using tcpserver on Linux system with admin rights throws Gtk-WARNING when client disconnects

Tags: linux, gtk, indy, tcpserver, disconnect

I'm setting up a new system using Indy 10.6 tcpserver on a Raspberry PI with the latest Raspbian loaded.  I am running the app from the GUI desktop via a terminal bash script with sudo.  Everything works fine until a client connects, then when it disconnects I get Gtk-WARNINGs, and some times Gtk-CRITICALs and I don't know why.  Here's my code, it only allows one client connection at a time, then it deactivates the server and restarts it after each connection is done:

```
Procedure TFK20Elevator.ASpeedBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin //start the server
  Server.Active := False;
  Server.Bindings.Clear;
  Server.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  Server.Bindings.Add.IP := LIP;
  Server.Bindings.Add.Port := DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0);
  Try
    Server.Active := True;
  Except
    On E: Exception Do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
  End;
  If Not Server.Active Then
    Exit;
  ASpeedBtn1.Enabled := False;
  ASpeedBtn2.Enabled := True;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Server bound to ' + LIP + ':' + IntToStr(DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0));
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
Begin
  If Connected Then
    Begin
      Abort();
      Exit;
    End;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Connecting to> ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' - Authenticating...';
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Manager := False;
  EncDecSIdx := 1;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := False;
  RetryTimer.Interval := 3000;
  Authenticating := True;
  AuthTimer.Enabled := True;
  StayAlive.Enabled := True;
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
Begin
  If AnsiContainsText(AException.Message, 'Gracefully') Then
    AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Server bound to ' + LIP + ':' + IntToStr(DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0)) //closed gracefully message
  Else
    Begin //show the exception
      Memo1.Lines.Add('An exception happend! - ' + AException.Message);
      RetryTimer.Enabled := True;
    End;
  Manager := False;
  Authenticating := False;
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
//EncStr and DecStr simply encode/decode, respectively, a standard
//  string into/from a key encrypted hex string, i.e. '00' to 'FF'
//  for each character in the string
Var
  S, UserName, Password: String;
  I, N: Integer;
Begin
  S := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault); //get the data
  If S = Heart Then //if message is the client heart beat, return to client
    Begin //just a heart beat, reset timer
      StayAlive.Enabled := False;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Heart, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
      StayAlive.Enabled := True;
      Exit;
    End;
  S := PCommon.DecStr(S, EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx); //not heart beat, decompress
  If Authenticating Then
    Begin //test log in
      If Length(S) > 3 Then
        Begin
          I := Pos('|', S);
          If (I > 1) And (Length(S) > I) Then
            Begin
              UserName := Copy(S, 1, I - 1);
              Password := Copy(S, I + 1, Length(S) - I);
              If UserName = ManUser Then
                Begin
                  If Password = ManPass Then
                    Begin
                      AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
                      Manager := True;
                      Authenticating := False;
                      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(EncStr(AContext.Binding.PeerIP +
                                                            ':' + IntToStr(DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0)) + 'M',
                                                            EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx), IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault,
                                                            IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
                      AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Connecting to> ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' as Manager';
                      Connected := True;
                    End
                  Else
                    AuthTimerTimer(Self);
                End
              Else If UserName = GenUser Then
                Begin
                  If Password = GenPass Then
                    Begin
                      AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
                      Authenticating := False;
                      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(EncStr(AContext.Binding.PeerIP +
                                                            ':' + IntToStr(DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0)) + 'U',
                                                            EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx), IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault,
                                                            IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
                      AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Connecting to> ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' as General User';
                      Connected := True;
                    End
                  Else
                    AuthTimerTimer(Self);
                End
              Else
                AuthTimerTimer(Self);
            End
          Else
            AuthTimerTimer(Self);
        End
      Else
        AuthTimerTimer(Self);
    End
  Else
    Begin //test for commands
      If Copy(S, 1, Length(AssignID)) = AssignID Then
        Begin //command to assign a new unit id
          NewLoc := DefLocation;
          NewUnit := DefUnitNum;
          I := Pos('-', S, 1);
          If (I > 0) And (I < Length(S)) Then
            Begin
              N := Pos('-', S, I + 1);
              If (N > 0) And (N < Length(S)) Then
                Begin
                  NewLoc := Copy(S, I + 1, N - I - 1);
                  NewUnit := Copy(S, N + 1, Length(S) - N);
                End;
            End;
          Label15.Caption := NewLoc;
          Label16.Caption := NewUnit;
          FmtStr(LIP, '%.3d', [StrToInt(NewUnit)]);
          LIP := '192.168.6' + Copy(LIP, 1, 1) + '.' + Copy(LIP, 2, 2); //wifi ip
          Memo1.Lines.Add('--> ' + S + '-' + LIP);
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(PCommon.EncStr(Rebooting, EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx),
                                                IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
          Memo1.Lines.Add('<-- ' + Rebooting);
          TestTimer.Enabled := True;
        End;
    End;
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.ASpeedBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin //shut down the server with optional restart if not rebooting
  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := False;
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  TestTimer.Enabled := False;
  DropClient;
  Try
    Server.Active := False;
  Except
    On E: Exception Do
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error disconnecting server - ' + E.Message);
  End;
  If Server.Active Then
    Exit;
  ASpeedBtn1.Enabled := True;
  ASpeedBtn2.Enabled := False;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Server not running...';
  Manager := False;
  Authenticating := False;
  Connected := False;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := Not SysReboot;
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
Begin
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := False;
  DropClient;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Client disconnected...';
  Manager := False;
  Authenticating := False;
  Connected := False;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := Not SysReboot;
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.DropClient; //make sure buffers are cleared
Var
  I: Integer;
  SC: TIdContext;
Begin
  If Server.Active Then
    Begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      With Server.Contexts.LockList Do
        Try
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Disconnecting...');
          For I := Count - 1 DownTo 0 Do
            Begin
              SC := TIdContext(Items[I]);
              If SC = Nil Then
                Continue;
              SC.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
              SC.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
              SC.Connection.IOHandler.Close;
              If SC.Connection.Connected Then
                SC.Connection.Disconnect;
              Memo1.Lines.Add('Disconnecting client ' + IntToStr(I + 1) + ' of ' + IntToStr(Count));
            End;
        Finally
          Server.Contexts.UnlockList;
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Disconnected');
        End;
    End;
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.StayAliveTimer(Sender: TObject);
Begin //server reset timer if client stops sending heart beat
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Client timed out!';
  If ASpeedBtn2.Enabled Then
    ASpeedBtn2Click(Self);
End;

Procedure TFK20Elevator.AuthTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
Begin //login authorization timeout timer
  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
  ASpeedBtn2Click(Self);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  ASpeedBtn1Click(Self);
End;
```

Comment: Also get a lot of Pango-CRITICALs as well.  Tried disabling DropClient in ServerDisconnect but that didn't help.

Comment: Some of the messages:

Comment: Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_context: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
    Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_get_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
    Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_get_metrics: assertion 'PANGO_IS_CONTEXT (context)' failed
    Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_font_metrics_get_approximate_char_width: assertion 'metrics != NULL' failed
    Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_font_metrics_get_approximate_digit_width: assertion 'metrics != NULL' failed
    etc.

Comment: The client program is actually running under Windows 10, written with Delphi 7, using Indy 10.6 as well.  Once login is confirmed, client sends a simple heart beat code every 3 seconds and resets its connection if the server doesn't return the code.

Comment: Also, a 2nd condition, if the client is connected, and is abruptly disconnected (I reset the program in debug mode), the server signals me that the client timed out, but then the program freezes.

Comment: "*it only allows one client connection at a time, then it deactivates the server and restarts it after each connection is done*" - `TIdTCPServer` is not really designed to be used that way. If you only want one client connected at a time, set the `TIdTCPServer.MaxConnections` property to 1, or consider using `TIdSimpleServer` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the SimpleServer possibility.  Let me know if you have any ideas on the cause of the problems.

Comment: I have a lot of ideas, I'm writing up an answer.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I really appreciate all your effort, your responses to others have really helped in getting me this far.  Did some checking into IdSimpleServer, but there doesn't seem to be any information/practical examples yes :(

Comment: I don't have specific examples of it. But in a nutshell, it is basically just a `TIdTCPConnection` with `(Begin)Listen()` methods added. Call `Listen()` to wait for a client connect, and then use the inherited `TIdTCPConnection` properties/methods as needed. Unlike `TIdTCPServer`, `TIdSimpleServer` is not threaded, so you would have to run it in your own thread. But it makes single-client servers much easier to use than `TIdTCPServer`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  Server.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
>  Server.Bindings.Add.IP := LIP;
>  Server.Bindings.Add.Port := DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0);
> ```

This is a bug in your code.  You are not opening just 1 listening socket, you are actually opening 3 listening sockets!  Every call to `Bindings.Add()` will tell `TIdTCPServer` to create a separate listening socket, and each Binding object has its own IP/Port settings.

What you are really doing with the above code is:

1. creating an IPv4 Binding on IP `0.0.0.0` on port `TIdTCPServer.DefaultPort`.
2. creating another Binding on IP `LIP` on port `TIdTCPServer.DefaultPort` using Indy's default IP version (which happens to be IPv4, unless you recompile Indy with `IdIPv6` defined in `IdCompilerDefines.inc`).
3. creating yet another Binding on IP `0.0.0.0` or `::1` on port `DefPort+UnitID` depending on Indy's default IP version.

For what you are attempting to do, you need to call `Bindings.Add()` *one time* only, eg:

```
var
  Binding : TIdSocketHandle;

Binding := Server.Bindings.Add;
Binding.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
Binding.IP := LIP;
Binding.Port := DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0);
```

That being said, `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Its various events (`OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute`, `OnException`, and `OnListenException`) are fired in the context of worker threads created internally by `TIdTCPServer`.  Your event handlers are directly accessing UI controls from outside the context of the main UI thread.  That causes all kinds of problems, and must never be done.

If your event handlers need to access your UI, they must synchronize with the main UI thread, such as with `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()`, or Indy's own `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class, or any other inter-thread synching mechanism of your choosing.

Also, when you go to manually drop clients with `DropClient()`, it is doing things to the contexts that it has no business doing.  You don't even need to drop the clients manually anyway, as `TIdTCPServer` handles that for you while it is being deactivated.

With all of that said, try something more like this:

```
interface

uses
  Classes, Form, SysUtils, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Buttons, IdTCPServer, IdContext;

type
  TFK20Elevator = class(TForm)
    Server: TIdTCPServer;
    ASpeedBtn1: TSpeedButton;
    ASpeedBtn2: TSpeedButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    AStatus1: TStatusBar;
    AuthTimer: TTimer;
    RetryTimer: TTimer;
    StayAlive: TTimer;
    TestTimer: TTimer;
    ...
    procedure ASpeedBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ASpeedBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StayAliveTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AuthTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure ServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure ServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
    procedure ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    ...
  private
    DefPort: Integer;
    UnitID: string;
    Manager: Boolean;
    Authenticating: Boolean;
    EncDecSIdx: Integer;
    ...
    procedure DropClient;
    procedure ConnectedNotify(const APeerIP: string);
    procedure DisconnectedNotify;
    procedure ErrorNotify(const AMessage: string);
    procedure HeartNotify;
    procedure ManagerLoggedInNotify(const APeerIP: string);
    procedure GeneralUserLoggedInNotify(const APeerIP: string);
    procedure FailedAuthNotify;
    procedure RebootNotify(const Data: string);
    ...
  end;

var
  FK20Elevator: TFK20Elevator;

implementation

uses
  IdGlobal, IdSync;

const
  Heart: string = ...;
  AssignID: string = ...;
  ...

procedure TFK20Elevator.ASpeedBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  //start the server

  Server.Active := False;
  Server.Bindings.Clear;
  Binding := Server.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  Binding.IP := LIP;
  Binding.Port := DefPort + StrToIntDef(UnitID, 0);
  Server.MaxConnections := 1;

  try
    Server.Active := True;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error activating server - ' + E.Message);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Server bound to ' + Binding.IP + ':' + IntToStr(Binding.Port);

  ASpeedBtn1.Enabled := False;
  ASpeedBtn2.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ASpeedBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //shut down the server with optional restart if not rebooting

  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := False;
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  TestTimer.Enabled := False;

  try
    Server.Active := False;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error deactivating server - ' + E.Message);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Manager := False;
  Authenticating := False;

  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Server not running...';
  ASpeedBtn1.Enabled := True;
  ASpeedBtn2.Enabled := False;

  RetryTimer.Enabled := not SysReboot;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.StayAliveTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //client stopped sending heart beats
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client timed out!');
  DropClient;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.AuthTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //login authorization timeout
  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Authentication timed out!');
  DropClient;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.DropClient;
begin
  with Server.Contexts.LockList do
  try
    if Count > 0 then
      TIdContext(Items[0]).Connection.Disconnect;        
  finally
    Server.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

type
  TMyNotifyMethod = procedure(const AStr: string) of object;

  TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    FMethod: TMyNotifyMethod;
    FStr: string;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    class procedure NotifyStr(AMethod: TMyNotifyMethod; const AStr: string);
  end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  FMethod(FStr);
end;

class procedure TMyNotify.NotifyStr(AMethod: TMyNotifyMethod; const AStr: string);
begin
  with Create do
  begin
    FMethod := AMethod;
    FStr := AStr;
    Notify;
  end;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ConnectedNotify(const APeerIP: string);
begin
  if not Server.Active then Exit;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Connecting to> ' + APeerIP + ' - Authenticating...';
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := False;
  RetryTimer.Interval := 3000;
  AuthTimer.Enabled := True;
  StayAlive.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.DisconnectedNotify;
begin
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  RetryTimer.Enabled := False;

  if Server.Active then
  begin
    with Server.Bindings[0] do
      AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Client Disconnected. Server bound to ' + IP + ':' + IntToStr(Port);
  end;

  RetryTimer.Enabled := Not SysReboot;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ErrorNotify(const AMessage: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('An exception happened! - ' + AMessage);
  RetryTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.HeartNotify;
begin
  StayAlive.Enabled := False;
  StayAlive.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ManagerLoggedInNotify(const APeerIP: string);
begin
  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Connecting to> ' + APeerIP + ' as Manager';
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.GeneralUserLoggedInNotify(const APeerIP: string);
begin
  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
  AStatus1.SimpleText := 'Connecting to> ' + APeerIP + ' as General User';
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.FailedAuthNotify;
begin
  //login authorization failed
  AuthTimer.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.RebootNotify(const Data: string);
var
  Tmp, S, NewLoc, NewUnit, LIP: string;
begin
  Tmp := Data;

  S := Fetch(Tmp, #10);
  NewLoc := Fetch(Tmp, #10);
  NewUnit := Tmp;

  Label15.Caption := NewLoc;
  Label16.Caption := NewUnit;

  FmtStr(LIP, '%.3d', [StrToInt(NewUnit)]);
  LIP := '192.168.6' + Copy(LIP, 1, 1) + '.' + Copy(LIP, 2, 2); //wifi ip

  Memo1.Lines.Add('--> ' + S + '-' + LIP);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('<-- ' + Rebooting);

  TestTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Manager := False;
  Authenticating := True;
  EncDecSIdx := 1;

  TMyNotify.NotifyStr(@ConnectedNotify, AContext.Binding.PeerIP);

  // Note: OSDefault is platform-specific. On Linux, it is UTF-8, so
  // you should use UTF-8 explicitly instead, so as to provide
  // better compatibility across platforms, especially if you ever
  // move this server code to another platform in the future...
  //
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault; // IndyTextEncoding_UTF8
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault; // IndyTextEncoding_UTF8
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Manager := False;
  Authenticating := False;
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(@DisconnectedNotify);
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  if not (AException is EIdConnClosedGracefully) then
    TMyNotify.NotifyStr(@ErrorNotify, AException.Message);
end;

procedure TFK20Elevator.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  S, Tmp, UserName, Password: String;
begin
  S := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn; //get the data
  if S = Heart then
  begin
    //just a heart beat, return to client and reset timer
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Heart);
    TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(@HeartNotify);
    Exit;
  end;

  //not heart beat, decompress
  //EncStr and DecStr simply encode/decode, respectively, a standard
  //  string into/from a key encrypted hex string, i.e. '00' to 'FF'
  //  for each character in the string

  S := PCommon.DecStr(S, EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx);

  if Authenticating then
  begin
    //test log in
    UserName := Fetch(S, '|');
    Password := S;

    if (UserName = ManUser) and (Password = ManPass) then
    begin
      Authenticating := False;
      Manager := True;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(EncStr(AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ':' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) + 'M', EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx));
      TMyNotify.NotifyStr(@ManagerLoggedInNotify, AContext.Binding.PeerIP);
    end
    else if (UserName = GenUser) and (Password = GenPass) then
    begin
      Authenticating := False;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(EncStr(AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ':' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) + 'U', EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx));
      TMyNotify.NotifyStr(@GeneralUserLoggedInNotify, AContext.Binding.PeerIP);
    end else
    begin
      TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(@FailedAuthNotify);
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    end;
    Exit;
  end;

  //test for commands
  if TextStartsWith(S, AssignID) then
  begin
    //command to assign a new unit id

    Tmp := S;
    Fetch(Tmp, '-');
    NewLoc := Fetch(Tmp, '-');
    NewUnit := Tmp;

    if (NewLoc = '') or (NewUnit = '') then
    begin
      NewLoc := DefLocation;
      NewUnit := DefUnitNum;
    end;

    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(PCommon.EncStr(Rebooting, EncDecStr, EncDecSIdx));

    TMyNotify.NotifyStr(@RebootNotify, S + #10 + NewLoc + #10 + NewUnit);
  end;
end;
```

Lastly, I would suggest you consider getting rid of all your global variables and heartbeat/authentication timers from the main UI thread.  Do timeout handling inside of the `OnExecute` event itself instead, such as making use of the client's `ReadTimeout` property and/or `CheckForDataOnSource()` method.  Use the `TIdContext.Data` property (or derive a new class from `TIdServerContext` and assign it to the `TIdTCPServer.ContextClass` property) to keep track of per-connection values, like the last time a heartbeat was received, or whether the client is still authenticating (actually, you should handle authentication in the `OnConnect` before `OnExecute` even starts running), or whether the client is logged in as a manager, etc.  That will reduce the amount of things that needs to be synchronized with the main UI thread, and avoid any timing issues introduced by delays in sync processing.

Comment: Great, thanks Remy, I'll implement it first thing tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: I modified the code, and learned a lot, but I'm not familiar with using classes like that for the notifies and don't know how to word them for the compiler, so when I compile, it tells me "Error: class identifier expected" at each of the notify procedures.

Comment: @user7475089 you have a `TFK20Elevator` class. Did you add the additional methods to that class's declaration in the unit's `interface`?

Comment: I added this under interface after uses: 

Type
  TMyNotifyMethod = Procedure(Const AStr: String) Of Object;
  TMyNotify = Class(TIdNotify)
  Protected
    FMethod: TMyNotifyMethod;
    FStr: String;
    Procedure DoNotify; Override;
  Public
    Class Procedure NotifyStr(AMethod: TMyNotifyMethod; Const AStr: String);
  End;

  { TFK20Elevator }

  TFK20Elevator = Class(TForm)

Comment: Then this under private:

    Procedure ConnectedNotify(Const APeerIP: String);
    Procedure DisconnectedNotify;
    Procedure ErrorNotify(Const AMessage: String);
    Procedure HeartNotify;
    Procedure ManagerLoggedInNotify(Const APeerIP: String);
    Procedure GeneralUserLoggedInNotify(Const APeerIP: String);
    Procedure FailedAuthNotify;
    Procedure RebootNotify(Const Data: String);

Comment: I updated my answer to show what it should look like.

Comment: Found the bug, the ConnectedNotify doesn't have the T in front of the FK20Elevator, proceeding further...

Comment: Now it's throwing a compiler error for too many parameters for the NotifyStr statements, i.e. TMyNotify.NotifyStr(ConnectedNotify, AContext.Binding.PeerIP); highlights ConnectedNotify with this error: Error: wrong number of parameters specified for "ConnectedNotify"

Comment: Since I'm compiling for Linux, under Lazarus, I'm thinking it needs an @ before the procedure names (@ConnectedNotify).

Comment: That did it Remy, you da bom, thanks for all the help :)